# What is the difference between Field and StringField in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I am searching for exactly matched document titles in lucene index. To accomplish that, I have the following two alternative approach to create fields for documents which will be indexed.

Approach 1:

```
FieldType _contentFieldType = new FieldType();
_contentFieldType.setIndexed(true);
_contentFieldType.setStored(true);

Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("content", getContent(), _contentFieldType));
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

Approach 2:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("content", getContent(), Store.YES));
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

Then i am creating query using `TermQuery` and searching in the lucene index but i don't get any result if i use the first approach. Second appoach is working fine for me.

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term(searchQuery.fields().get(0), searchQuery.queryText()));
indexSearcher.search(query, Math.max(1, collector.getTotalHits()));
```

Example of document titles: Document titles are actually topic of the document, a hierarchical path of topics.

```
Top/Arts/Animation/Audio
Top/Arts/Animation/Collectibles
Top/Arts/Animation/Stop-Motion
Top/Arts/Animation/Festivals
Top/Arts/Animation/News_and_Media
Top/Arts/Animation/Chats_and_Forums
Top/Arts/Animation/Training
Top/Arts/Animation/Voice_Actors
Top/Arts/Animation/Artists
```

Say, i want to search for `Top/Arts/Animation/Training`. I need exact string matching, so i have used `TermQuery`.

I read documentation and learned about Field and StringField. So, StringField is indexed but not analyzed if `Store.Yes` is passed as parameter. But my question is, since i am using both `setIndexed(true)` and `setStored(true)` for `Field` in approach 1, why i am not getting similar result from approach 1? Is it because some additional things are executed if i use Field or is it because of the use of TermQuery? What is the main thing that is making this two approaches different? Please help me to understand the difference in them.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give an example of the value you are trying to search ?

Comment: what is the tokenizer you are using ?

Comment: i am not tokenizing anything. Because i have queries with one term only. So, no tokenization is used.

Comment: how are you building index ? can you post the analyzer you are using to create the index ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128553/discussion-between-root545-and-wasi-ahmad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I am thinking is happening.

You used  an `analyzer` for indexing which lower cases input tokens in your first approach.

so e.g  `Top/Arts/Animation/Training` this will be stored as following

> top/Arts/animation/training

now when you search it using `TERMQUERY`, the termquery actually search for the exact string. i.e `Top/Arts/Animation/Training` which wont match anything because of the lower case in the indexes.

Lets talk about second approach. Since you used StringField, the fields are not analyzed and will be stored as it is. i.e your index contains the following in the StringField case

> Top/Arts/Animation/Training

So now when you search using TermQuery this will match because it is stored as it is.

To get results in the first approach

Use a `QueryParser` to construct the query instead of using `TermQuery` using the same analyser used at indexing time.

Read here for difference between `TERMQUERY` and `QUERYPARSER`

[what is the difference between TermQuery and QueryParser in Lucene 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467591/what-is-the-difference-between-termquery-and-queryparser-in-lucene-6-0/40475819#40475819)

**EDIT**

The stored just means that the original field value is stored in the index. so that it can be returned while returning search results. search happens on index and not on the stored value. The reason behind the stored attribute is that lucene "analyzes" or transforms the input data into a more efficient form for faster and more relevant search(using different analyzers and tokenizers). Unfortunately, that analyzed data is frequently no longer suitable for display. Setting "stored=true" guarantees that the original data can be retrieved in its original form.

Comment: Previously actually i did that. I have two more fields in the documents which uses Field but there is no impact of the analyzer in them. So, i am just wondering if what you have mentioned about the analyzer's function is correct, then how can i store and index two different field with two different content. One is stemmed and the other one is not!!

Comment: let me understand this. you are saying that you used the same writer which uses your "special indexer" to index these two other fields also ? and in those two fields you can do the searching using TERMQUERY? so essentially the lowercase is not affecting those searches ?

Comment: What i meant is, Given, setStored(yes) for Field and Store.Yes for StringField, how they are different? They should be the same but i am getting different behavior from them. And yes, strings are not in lowercase in index, i have checked that. TermQuery is considering the entire query as a single term but if i used QueryParser, it will split the query into several terms.

Comment: Why do you think setStored(yes) and Store.Yes,  has any impact on how index are stored ?

Comment: I think that they have the same impact but its not! I guess if i useField, some other operations executed, like normalization or tokenization which is not done if i use StringField. I just wanted to know is my understanding correct or not!

Comment: The stored just means that the original field value is stored in the index. so that it can be returned while returning search results. search happens on index and not on the stored value. The reason behind the stored attribute is that lucene "analyzes" or transforms the input data into a more efficient form for faster and more relevant search(using different analyzers and tokenizers). Unfortunately, that analyzed data is frequently no longer suitable for display. Setting "stored=true" guarantees that the original data can be retrieved in its original form.

Comment: I have accepted it. Please add your last comment in the answer which was most helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

StringField is not tokenized (that is, it won't be run through the analyzer to be split into tokens). Your FieldType will default to being tokenized unless you specify otherwise, so call `setTokenized(false)` (Note: it appears you are using version 4.10 or earlier, so I'll assume 4.10. It's helpful to state this though, since the FieldType API has changed somewhat since then):

```
FieldType _contentFieldType = new FieldType();
_contentFieldType.setIndexed(true);
_contentFieldType.setStored(true);
_contentFieldType.setTokenized(false);
```

Alternatively, you could duplicate the `StringField.TYPE_STORED` FieldType, to get a new modifiable FieldType with settings identical to that of StringField, like this:

```
FieldType _contentFieldType = new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED);
```