# Lucene query: TermQuery doesn't work but QueryParser works

Tags: lucene, python-3.8, pylucene

```
    def searchGiustizia(self,startPagination,recPerPage):
        indexPath = File(self.fileLucene).toPath()
        directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath)
        searcher = IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory))

        paQuery5 = TermQuery(Term("parte","TELESI RICCARDO"))
        
        analyzer = StandardAnalyzer()



        print ("\n------------------------------------------------------")
        start = datetime.now()
        collector = TotalHitCountCollector()
        searcher.search(paQuery5, collector)
        print("found: ",collector.getTotalHits())

        scoreCollector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(collector.getTotalHits(), 0)
    
        searcher.search(paQuery5, scoreCollector)
        scoreDocs = scoreCollector.topDocs(startPagination, recPerPage).scoreDocs
        duration = datetime.now() - start
        print("paginata ",str(duration))
        for scoreDoc in scoreDocs:
            doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc)
            print (doc.get("cf_giudice")," ",
            doc.get("codiceoggetto")," ",
            doc.get("parte")," ",
            doc.get("distretto"))
        print ("\n------------------------------------------------------")
```

The function try to search "TELESI RICCARDO" in lucene index.
This  search function return zeros results. Why?
I have TELESI RICCARDO as parte field indexed in lucene. If I try the same query using  QueryParser it work like this:

```
    def searchGiustizia(self,startPagination,recPerPage):
        indexPath = File(self.fileLucene).toPath()
        directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath)
        searcher = IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory))
        
        analyzer = StandardAnalyzer()
        queryParser = QueryParser("parte", analyzer)
        queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
        paQuery4 = queryParser.parse("TELESI RICCARDO");

        print ("\n------------------------------------------------------")
        start = datetime.now()
        collector = TotalHitCountCollector()
        searcher.search(paQuery4, collector)
        print("trovati: ",collector.getTotalHits())

        scoreCollector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(collector.getTotalHits(), 0)
    
        searcher.search(paQuery4, scoreCollector)
        scoreDocs = scoreCollector.topDocs(startPagination, recPerPage).scoreDocs
        duration = datetime.now() - start
        print("paginata ",str(duration))
        for scoreDoc in scoreDocs:
            doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc)
            print (doc.get("cf_giudice")," ",
            doc.get("codiceoggetto")," ",
            doc.get("parte")," ",
            doc.get("distretto"))
        print ("\n------------------------------------------------------")
```

This QueryParser work perfectly but TermQuery doesn't.

Comment: They are not the same queries. In a term query, the text you are searching for is treated as a single term: `TELESI RICCARDO`. I expect your index does not contain that term anywhere. Instead it contains the term `TELESI` and another term `RICCARDO`. So there are no matches. Your query parser searches for all documents containing both the separate terms `TELESI` and `RICCARDO` (using `QueryParser.Operator.AND`) - and therefore it finds a document containing those two tokens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between TermQuery and QueryParser in Lucene 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467591/what-is-the-difference-between-termquery-and-queryparser-in-lucene-6-0)

Comment: I have tested with field "string", indeed TermQuery run well. TermQuery search "TELESI RICCARDO" match exact "TELESI RICCARDO" on field type string. ParseQuery run on field type "text" and I can do research for both terms TELESI and RICCARDO (using QueryParser.Operator.AND)